# Visualforce: Issues with $Permission when rerendering

Tags: visualforce, permissions, rerender, custom-permission

Has anyone else experienced issues with permission based elements on visualforce when rerendering a section?

For example I have a section that for administrators will provide a link but for common users it would just display the text like so:

```html
<apex:repeat id="myRepeat">
    <apex:outpanel id="myWrapper"
    <!-- If user has admin permissions -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Permission.AdminPermission}">
        <a href="/{!record.Id}" target="_blank">
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block">Record# {!record.Id}</apex:outputPanel>
        </a>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- If user does NOT have admin permissions -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!$Permission.AdminPermission}">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">Record# {!record.Id}</apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- Input text with onchange actionFunction method -->
    <apex:inputText value="{!rowUnits}" onChange="updateUnits(this)"/>
</apex:repeat>

<!-- Action Functions -->
<apex:actionFunction 
    action="{!setUnits}" 
    name="updateUnitsAction" 
    reRender="{!$Component.myRepeat.myWrapper}">
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!process}" rerender="errors, {!$Component.myRepeat.myWrapper}/>
```

When the page first loads this works exactly as expected but then when I rerender the section that contains this portion of markup the permission that once worked (granting the link) is now false (showing just the text). If I refresh the page I again have the admin link.

Appreciate any feedback, thanks!

**Edited with command button, inputtext onchange, and wrapper section markup**

Comment: Just a couple comments, but better to use `NOT` inside a merge field than `!` especially first thing. Also better to do `{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.View, record.Id)}` than `/{!record.Id}`.

Comment: What happens if you store the results of that `$Permission` outside the repeat using an `apex:variable` tag? Might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... the comments and previous answer were very helpful (so thank you for them), I implemented them but the actual issue turned out to be because of the `<apex:outputPanel>`.

Apparently even without the permissions in play the hyperlink was being removed on `rerender` because the text was wrapped with an outputPanel. Luckily, I found another section where this was not an issue, it was using `<apex:outputText>` so I modified my scenario with that and it worked perfectly!

```html
<!-- If user has admin permissions -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Permission.AdminPermission}">
    <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.View, record.Id)}" target="_blank">
        <apex:outputText value="Record# {!record.Id}"></apex:outputText>
    </a>
</apex:outputPanel>
<!-- If user does NOT have admin permissions -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT $Permission.AdminPermission}">
    <apex:outputText>Record# {!record.Id}</apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not there in this section of code which you have shared.

The issue lies how your are re-rendering this section. Are you using click event action function or controller action which is re-rendering these output panels?

If you mind to share the code on how you are re-rendering.

Comment: Edited my post, added `with sharing` to my controller as well but that didn't seem to fix anything